# How do I accept multiple optional parameters in a Spring request mapping, but only one at a time?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

Edit: I ended up solving the problem myself through more experimentation. The code seems quite verbose though so there is probably a better solution that doesn't involve typecasting strings to other things.

Answer posted below.

---

For my school work, I am supposed to create a GET mapping to receive a list of all entities of a specific type. This GET mapping should return simply all the entities if no parameter is provided, or otherwise it will apply something in the entity repository to use a JPQL query and the provided parameter which is used as an ordinal query parameter to filter the returned results.

*"If no request parameter is provided, the existing functionality of returning all events
should be retained.
If more than one request parameter is specified, an error response should be
returned, indicating that at most one parameter can be provided.
If the ‘?status=XXX’ parameter is provided, with a status string value that does not
match the AEventStatus enumeration, an appropriate error response should be
returned."*

I have tried to alter my GET mapping to have 3 optional @RequestParameter variables, but I found out that it is tedious logic-wise to check for the existence of multiple or no parameters, and then do something again based on the existence of which parameter is there.

Instead I tried this (I was in the middle of this and it is not complete):

```
  @RequestMapping(
    value="/aevents",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllAEvents(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getParameterMap().size() == 0) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(repository.findAll());
    }
    if (request.getParameterMap().size() > 1) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Can only handle one request paramter: title=, status= or minRegistrastions=", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    //incomplete from here
  }
```

And I am now not sure if this is the correct approach or if I am simply overlooking something. I suppose I might be able to check for the names of the parameters that were provided in the request and then return a bad request response again if I find something that isn't a valid parameter. But I am not sure how to check the parameter map for the names of the parameters or if the parameter map even does what I think it does.

The parameters provided are supposed to be either an int, a value from an enum or a string.

Am I overlooking a simpler way to do this? i.e. a way to check the amount of parameters and the existence of parameters in a signature like:

```
  @GetMapping("/aevents")
  public List<AEvent> getAllAEvents(@RequestParam(required = false) String title,
                                    @RequestParam(required = false) AEventStatus status,
                                    @RequestParam(required = false) int minRegistrations) {
                                        //Do something here
                                  }
```

Or is my current approach feasible, and if it is, how do I continue on it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would likely do it your way, though:

1. You can inject the map of parameters directly in Spring.
2. Throw a ResponseStatusException (available since Spring 5) instead of fumbling around with the ResponseEntity.

   ```
   @GetMapping("/aevents")
   public List<AEvent> getAllAEvents( @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams){

     if(allRequestParams.size() >1){
         throw new ResponseStatusException(
               HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"too many params");
     }

     // do something
     return list;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question after solving it:

**What is the parameter map?**
The parameterMap is actually a map of string keys and string arrays. To get the value for a parameter name (the key) you can get values of this key and then access it like an array.
However, using the parameterMap was not necessary. Instead it was better to just use the built-in Spring way of doing it which is by using the @RequestParam annotation with simply a `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params` in the method body.

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255293/marco-behler for giving me an idea as well as providing a better way to throw exceptions.

```
  @GetMapping("/aevents")
  public List<AEvent> getAllAEvents(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    if (params.size() == 0) { //Default case, no params
      return repository.findAll();
    }
    if (params.size() > 1) { //Refuse to handle more than one provided param
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Can only handle one request parameter: title=, status= or minRegistrations=");
    }
    if (params.containsKey("title")) {
      String value = params.get("title");
      return repository.findByQuery("AEvent_find_by_title", ("%" + value + "%"));
    }
    if (params.containsKey("status")) {
      String stringValue = params.get("status").toUpperCase();
      for (AEventStatus e : AEventStatus.values()) {
        if (e.name().equals(stringValue)) {
          AEventStatus value = AEventStatus.valueOf(stringValue);
          return repository.findByQuery("AEvent_find_by_status", value);
        }
      }
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "status=" + stringValue + " is not a valid AEvent status value.");
    }
    if (params.containsKey("minRegistrations")) {
      int value;
      try {
        value = Integer.parseInt(params.get("minRegistrations"));
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Provided request parameter was not a valid number.");
      }
      return repository.findByQuery("AEvent_find_by_minRegistrations", value);
    }
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid query parameters.");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think you can even make it nicer by injecting the parametermap directly. Anyway, good that it works :)

Comment: @MarcoBehler Thanks, I've updated the code a little bit :)